# Pausing a game using pygame by pressing two keys simultaneously - tamagotchi project

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, pygame, keyboard-events

I'm trying to implement a pause function in my tamagotchi clone (I'm practising for my controlled assessment next year) and I can't get the left and up keys to work simultaneously as a pause button. If possible I want to stay as true to the original game as possible so I would prefer not to use on-screen buttons. Thanks!

```
    import pygame
    import time

    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

    size =(200, 200)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Tama v4.5')
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.init()

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    sprites = ['AdultSpriteAAA.png']

    up_pressed = False
    left_pressed = False
    right_pressed = False

    def main():
        controls()
        if up_pressed == True and left_pressed == True:
            time.sleep(2)
            pause()
        player_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        x = player_position[0]
        y = player_position[1]
        screen.blit(background, [0,0])
        screen.blit(sprite, [x, y])

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

    def controls():
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print(animate())
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    global up_pressed
                    right_pressed = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    global left_pressed
                    left_pressed = True
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    global right_pressed
                    right_pressed = True

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    global up_pressed
                    right_pressed = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    global left_pressed
                    left_pressed = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    global right_pressed
                    right_pressed = False

    def info():
        return 0

    def food():
        return 1

    def toilet():
        return 2

    def game():
        return 3

    def connect():
        return 4

    def talk():
        return 5

    def medic():
        return 6

    def post():
        return 7

    def history():
        return 8

    def animate():
        return 9

    def pause():
        time.sleep(2)
        while True:
            controls()
            if up_pressed == True and left_pressed == True:
                time.sleep(2)
                break


    sprite = pygame.image.load(sprites[0]).convert()
    background = pygame.image.load('Background 200x200.png').convert()

    sprite.set_colorkey(BLACK)

    while True:
        main()
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to make it pause when both left iey and up key are pressed is this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
#game code
…
def pause():
    keyspressed = pygame.keys.get_pressed()
    if keyspressed[K_LEFT] and keyspressed[K_UP]:
        #pause code
        …
```

This code should be correct, but if you find any weird things, try to research the pygame key module. Keep in note that K_LEFT and K_UP are from pygame.locals, which is imported seperately from pygame

Comment: keyspressed is a worse method of gathering keypresses because it allows you to spam keypresses, which would presumably open and close the pause menu extremely quickly if you mapped open and close to the same keys. The event method works much better.

Comment: But couldn't you also set a timer?

Comment: Yes, but why go through doing that when you can use the easier builtin solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that I have found really useful when writing games in PyGame:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN 
    if event.key == (pygame.K_RIGHT and pygame.K_LEFT):
        while True: # Infinite loop that will be broken when the user press the space bar again
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:  # decid how to unpause?
                break #Exit infinite loop
```

An interesting tid-bit I only recently discovered is that pygame.key.get_pressed() returns a tuple of 1s and 0s representing all of the keys on the keyboard, and these can be used as booleans or indexed to get the effective "value" of a key.  Some great tuts at http://programarcadegames.com/